# Koltin TableView

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I have a tableView table in Kotlin and I take a number from the user for that table, equate the tableRow and tableColumn to the number entered by the user, and create a table as large as the number entered by the user. And I fill that table with random true and false. What I want to do is find how many true and false there are side by side in that table and print it below to the textView. For example, if there are 2 true side by side, it should write 1 to the text view, if there are 2 false side by side, it should write to the textView. I want your help for this. Below is the code I wrote:

```
private fun findInTable(n:Int){
        tableLayout = findViewById(R.id.tableLayout)
        tableLayout.removeAllViews()

        var count = 0
        var tfSum = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.sonuc2)
        var previousValue = ""
        for (i in 1..n) {
            val tableRow = TableRow(this)

            for (j in 1..n) {
                val textView = TextView(this)
                if (textView != null) {
                    val randomBoolean = (0..1).random() == 1
                    val value = textView.text.toString()
                    textView.text = randomBoolean.toString()
                    tableRow.addView(textView)

                    if (value == previousValue) {
                        count++
                    } else {
                        if (count > 1) {
                            tfSum.text = ("$count adet $previousValue yan yana bulundu.")
                        }
                        count = 1
                        previousValue = value
                    }
                }
            }
            if (count > 1) {
                tfSum.text = ("$count adet $previousValue yan yana bulundu.")
            }
            count = 0
            previousValue = ""

            tableLayout.addView(tableRow)
        }

        val textViewSum = TextView(this)
        textViewSum.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
        textViewSum.setPadding(16, 16, 16, 16)
    }
```

This is my table looks like :

[image: Table]

This is my table. Above, the user enters a number, creates a table according to the number entered and fills it with true and false. It also prints the result to the textView below, but it prints incorrectly. It says how many lines there are. I don't understand I would be glad if you help.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is in this below code statement

```
val value = textView.text.toString()
```

as the value is always empty as we initialize it so it always empty string so in the condition `if (value == previousValue)` will always be **true** so **count** will be **n** in all cases, we need to change its place to be after this below code statement to always have the new value after generating random value

```
textView.text = randomBoolean.toString()
```

so the final code. should be like this in the right order

```
                val randomBoolean = (0..1).random() == 1
                textView.text = randomBoolean.toString()
                val value = textView.text.toString()
                tableRow.addView(textView)
```

Comment: this is what i'm trying to say, It will print how many side-by-side true or false there are, take the same values ​​next to each other, and write to the textView that this number of adjacent elements was found.

Comment: Ok first based on the question the issue that it always print the number entered not the count so this is the reason of it ...  second can you clarify what's output expected for example count across all the table of adjacent elements in same row ?